# msal-browser error hash_does_not_contain_known_properties

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, azure-ad-msal

I get this error when login popup msal-browser :

> hash_does_not_contain_known_properties

[image]

> Error - PopupHandler.monitorPopupForHash - found hash in url but it does not contain known properties. Check that your router is not changing the hash prematurely.

error occurs when logging in using a mobile browser (chrome, safari, etc)

this is my config msal [image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSTnb.png)]

and this is my authentication redirect uri in portal azure [image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrHzR.png)]

this is my url when login https://vue-msal-browser.netlify.app/#/sign-in

```
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.38.0",
"vue": "^3.2.13",
"vue-router": "^4.2.4"
```

Hope you can help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the code as text rather than from post image ?

Comment: i have edited, please help me @Will